# Python "for line in file", read the next n lines

Tags: python

I am trying to create a few graphs from a text file, each depending of the flow rate of the test saved in the file (50000000bps, 100000000bps, ...).

A part of the file :

```
Test n4721 : 100000000bps
 > ping request = 756811
 > ping reply = 338566
 > Loss = 55.26412803196571%

Loss from start : 89.43101573304583%
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -


Test n4722 : 50000000bps
 > ping request = 378405
 > ping reply = 195513
 > Loss = 48.33234233162881%

Loss from start : 89.42231207497692%
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

I am opening the file with `file = open("result.txt","r")` and going through it with `for line in file:`.

When an if loop coresponding to a flow rate match a line (ie "50000000bps"), I need to append to an array the value of the next lines : `Loss` and `Loss from start`.

This is how my code is going from now :

```py
file = open("result.txt","r")

for line in file:
    count += 1

    if "50000000" in line:
        current_loss = line(count + 3) # Don't work, like : line[count + 3] file[count + 3]
        print(current_loss)

        start_loss = line(count + 5) # Don't work, like : line[count + 5] file[count + 5]
        print(start_loss)
```

Do you know how can I read the next n line from the one I am curently reading ?

Comment: `for line in file` isn't the only way to iterate over a file's lines. You can access the iterator interface directly, or you can use `readline()`, etc.

Comment: if you must use a for loop, you can first create a list of lines using `readlines` and then iterate it (without the file default iterator)

Comment: BTW, `"50000000" in line` is a bit dangerous, because it'll still be true if you tack an extra `0` onto the end of that number. Safer if you make it `"50000000bps" in line`, so adding more 0s to the end won't make false matches. Even better to match at the beginning too, f/e, `: 50000000bps" in line`, so something like `150000000bps` also won't match.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the info because I will match 10 000 000 and 100 000 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `readline()` every time you want to read another line from your input file. For your given logic, then, that might look like:

```
infile = open("result.txt","r")

for line in infile:
    if "50000000bps" in line:
        _, _, loss = infile.readline(), infile.readline(), infile.readline()
        _, loss_from_start = infile.readline(), infile.readline()
        print(loss.rstrip())
        print(loss_from_start.rstrip())
```

See this running at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/RoughTreasuredFolders#main.py

Comment: Thanks for the link to this website and your edit from the while to a for loop (while wasnt working for me). Can you explain what is `_,` ? And why did you put multiple .`readlines()` ?

Comment: `_` is a convention for a generic placeholder variable. The multiple `readline()`s are to read and ignore the lines we don't care about.

Comment: @user161458 so, `_, _, loss = infile.readline(), infile.readline(), infile.readline()` reads three lines, but it throws away the first two by assigning them to `_`; only `loss` is retained somewhere conventionally meaningful.

Comment: @user161458, the original `while` loop syntax required a Python new enough to support `:=` (assignment as an expression rather than a statement). If you had a sufficiently recent Python (3.9, certainly, maybe 3.8) it would work; but it wasn't necessary, hence backing out to the syntax compatible with older releases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop inside your file lines, you can use:

```
file = open("result.txt","r")
file_lines = file.readlines()

for line in file_lines:

#rest of your code
```

To get your Kth line from your lines:

```
file = open("result.txt","r")
file_lines = file.readlines()

for k in range(len(file_lines)):
     kth_line = file_lines[k]
```

Comment: Hardly efficient, though, to read everything into memory before you start processing. The OP's code avoided needing to store more than a line at a time in RAM.